# why does asyncio_ensure_future = asyncio.async raise a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i've been looking all over the the internet and back for an answer, but nothing comes up.

i assume this may or may not be a very rare.
it seems im the only one with this probably to be honest.

heres the error that comes up V

`import discord
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .voice_client import VoiceClient
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 43, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .protocol import CONNECTING, OPEN, WebSocketCommonProtocol
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .compatibility import asyncio_ensure_future
  File "C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\compatibility.py", line 9
    from asyncio import async as asyncio_ensure_future
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

im using python 3.7.0, the latest version.

trust me, i've been spending like 15 to 20 minutes trying to find a solution,
**s a v e m e f r o m t h i s m a d n e s s**

Answer (score 0):

The version of `discord.py` available from `pip` doesn't support Python 3.7 (because `async` and `await` were made keywords)

Try downloading the latest development version of the library from Github

```
python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

Comment: install --record C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7b7fuos3\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hmm46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uwibbfxc\PyNaCl\

Comment: Does your bot require voice?  You could also try `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py`